# Wordpress and Jquery slide

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am integrating a Jquery slider inside of wordpress here is the [demo](http://gadgetinspiration.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/jquery%20sliders/index.html) of the slider.

I can see the div that is their but for some reason it is not showing up. View the working site [here](http://www.testground.idghosting.com/philcom/home/)

Now my problem is that this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _siteRoot='index.php',_root='index.php';</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

represents and index.html, but in wordpress I enabled permalinks. Any clue what would be the _siteRoot is?

here is the complete code

**HEADER**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _siteRoot='index.php',_root='index.php';</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Here are the images:

```
<div id="slide-holder">
<div id="slide-runner">
    <a href=""><img id="slide-img-1" src="images/nature-photo.png" class="slide" alt="" /></a>
    <a href=""><img id="slide-img-2" src="images/nature-photo1.png" class="slide" alt="" /></a>
    <a href=""><img id="slide-img-3" src="images/nature-photo2.png" class="slide" alt="" /></a>
    <a href=""><img id="slide-img-4" src="images/nature-photo3.png" class="slide" alt="" /></a>
    <a href=""><img id="slide-img-5" src="images/nature-photo4.png" class="slide" alt="" /></a>
    <a href=""><img id="slide-img-6" src="images/nature-photo4.png" class="slide" alt="" /></a>
    <a href=""><img id="slide-img-7" src="images/nature-photo6.png" class="slide" alt="" /></a> 
    <div id="slide-controls">
     <p id="slide-client" class="text"><strong>post: </strong><span></span></p>
     <p id="slide-desc" class="text"></p>
     <p id="slide-nav"></p>
    </div>
</div>

    <!--content featured gallery here -->
   </div>
```

**And the footer**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(!window.slider) var slider={};slider.data=[{"id":"slide-img-1"},{"id":"slide-img-2"},{"id":"slide-img-3"},{"id":"slide-img-4"},{"id":"slide-img-5"},{"id":"slide-img-6"},{"id":"slide-img-7"},{"id":"slide-img-8"}];
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're sticking WP vars / constants in javascript, I have the best success adding a javascscript in the top of my theme's header.php with some global vars.

Your particular settings could probably be done with:

```
var _siteRoot='<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>',
var _root='<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>';
```

Comment: That's because you have lots of other problems. If you inspect your DOM and view your images, the urls are correct:

http://www.testground.idghosting.com/philcom/wp-content/themes/phil/images/banner/testimonial1.gif

But I found at least one script is not loaded because it is returning 404 not found:

http://www.testground.idghosting.com/philcom/wp-content/themes/phil/js/scripts.js

That is causing some JS you have written inline in your page to be double printed, which could also cause issue.

Comment: ok now I got that working! thank you now my only problem is it doesn't automatically scroll

Comment: Have you checked your error console? Your script errors out, you are missing something: 

Error: text is undefined
Source File: http://www.testground.idghosting.com/philcom/wp-content/themes/phil/js/scripts.js
Line: 133

Comment: it has to do with this <script type="text/javascript">
var _siteRoot='index.php',_root='index.php';</script> so changed it to index.php but still is not working.

Comment: figured it ou I have to put descriptions in the footer script. so on the HTML that renders it I added a dtyle to display:none so now everything works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Good. Hope I could be of some help.